# Focus a chart control on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a chart control in my ASPX page. At the top of the page there are some dropdown boxes to select some parameters to draw chart control and a button. Initially the chart control is invisible. After the btton click the chart control databinding will be done and visible property is set true. How to make the Chart control to be focused where it is at the down of the page after button click. Where now after postback the user has to scroll down to view the chart.

Answer (score 1):

The focus property is a property inherited from WebControls that is triggered whenever the user is inputting data in a control (eg. a textbox).

Since the chart control does not allow (obviously) the user to input data directly, the chart cannot be focused.

There are however other workarounds to do that, you can use [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060422/center-item-on-screen-with-jquery) to center the image (all charts are rendered as an image) on the screen or [add another control](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/78467.aspx) at the bottom of the chart and set focus to that (you could add for instance a reset button).